# CSS :not() selector on all descendants

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How can I make it happen that the :not()-selector works in the following example?

**HTML**

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="one">
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
  <div id="two">
    <div class="mystyle"><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should NOT be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#content a:not(.mystyle) {
  color: green;
}
```

**JSFIDDLE**

[Link to jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avj1rg36/)

**Important**

I am trying to style an external widget on my blog. I don't have access to it's HTML so changing the HTML is not an option. I am looking for an CSS-only solution.

Comment: Could you please explain what you're trying to do here?

Comment: There are four links. All links should be green with one exception: the link in the class="mystyle".

Comment: Your fiddle is quite different from the code in your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example, the `:not()` selector is applied to the `a` element. This would only select `a` tags that did not have a `.mystyle` class on it.

```
#content > * > *:not(.mystyle) a {
    color: green;
}
```

The above will select any descendants 2 levels down that don't have a `.mystyle` class, then colour all their decendant `a` tags green.

Below is a working example:

```css
#content > div > div:not(.mystyle) a {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="one">
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
  <div id="two">
    <div class="mystyle"><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should NOT be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> There are four links. All links should be green with one exception: the link in the class="mystyle".

Then why are you using `:not()`? Just give the color to the existing class.

```css
* { color: green; }

.mystyle * { color: red; }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="one">
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
  <div id="two">
    <div class="mystyle"><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should NOT be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Seems like the answer I was going to post; http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LWGygY?editors=1100

Comment: I am trying to style a external widget (I dont't have access to it's HTML so changing the HTML is not an option!).

Comment: My answer doesn't change the HTML. Are you saying that the `mystyle` class doesn't really exist?

Answer (score 0):

Like that? :

```css
div:not(.mystyle) > p > a { color: green; }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="one">
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
  <div id="two">
    <div class="mystyle"><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should NOT be green -->
    <div><p>This is a <a href="">link</a>.</p></div> <!-- should be green -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do this you can check in the below snippet.

```css
div:not(.calc) > p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
<div><p>Hi</p></div>
<div ><div class="calc"><p>Hi</p></div></div>
<div><p>Hi</p></div>
</div>
```